# Change font color in shiny dashboard titlePanel

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to make the title of my dashboard in red, but when I try to pass the style argument in my titlePanel, I get an error that the argument is unused. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data", style = "color: #FFFFFF"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("bins",
                        "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here's the error:

```
Error in titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data", style = "color: #FFFFFF") : 
  unused argument (style = "color: #FFFFFF")
```

Comment: wrap it in a `div` as `titlePanel(div("Old Faithful Geyser Data", style = "color: #FF0000"))`

Comment: @YBS, that works! Do you want to submit as an answer and then I can accept and close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it in a `div` as

`titlePanel(div("Old Faithful Geyser Data", style = "color: #FF0000"))`